# Flink-orc: Could not find any format factory for identifier 'orc' in the classpath

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I need to save the table result to orc on S3, and this is how I do it:

```
tEnv.createTemporaryTable("my_output_table", TableDescriptor.forConnector("filesystem")
                .schema(outputSchema)
                .option("path", s3OutputPath)
                .format(FormatDescriptor.forFormat("orc").build())
                .build());
finalResultToInsert.executeInsert("my_output_table");
```

However, during runtime it throws error of

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any format factory for identifier 'orc' in the classpath.
    at org.apache.flink.table.filesystem.FileSystemTableSink.<init>(FileSystemTableSink.java:128) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.table.filesystem.FileSystemTableFactory.createDynamicTableSink(FileSystemTableFactory.java:87) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createTableSink(FactoryUtil.java:179) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.getTableSink(PlannerBase.scala:394) ~[flink-table_2.12-1.14.2.jar:1.14.2]
......
```

I have already included the relevant dependency

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-orc_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

And in the generated jar file I can see the flink orc classes:

```
org/apache/flink/orc/
org/apache/flink/orc/AbstractOrcFileInputFormat.class
org/apache/flink/orc/OrcFileFormatFactory$1.class
org/apache/flink/orc/OrcFilters$LessThanEquals.class
org/apache/flink/orc/AbstractOrcFileInputFormat$OrcVectorizedReader.class
org/apache/flink/orc/OrcFilters$Not.class
org/apache/flink/orc/OrcFileFormatFactory.class
org/apache/flink/orc/OrcColumnarRowSplitReader.class
org/apache/flink/orc/OrcColumnarRowSplitReader$ColumnBatchGenerator.class
org/apache/flink/orc/AbstractOrcFileInputFormat$OrcReaderBatch.class
org/apache/flink/orc/OrcFilters$In.class
......
```

So I really don't understand why it still can not find it in the classpath.

A side note, in the project I also include flink-avro dependency and if I change the output format from orc to avro it just works fine.

Also, I am running the job on AWS EMR. The EMR release is 6.6.0 which has Flink version of 1.14.2. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-660-release.html

Could anyone help with that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like I resolved the problem by placing

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-orc_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

To the top of the dependencies section in Maven pom, and it worked.
I think it is just due to the order of class loading, so put it in front might resolve the conflicts during the class loading for flink-orc dependency since it will be loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, ORC requires Hadoop. So you should also add org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common and potentially other Hadoop dependencies too.

Comment: I am running the flink job on EMR 6.6.0, so hadoop should already be there: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-660-release.html